# Ошибка С++: странные значения дат

Tags: c++, visual-c++, дата, структуры

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

struct date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
enum etype {laborer, secretary, manager, accountant, executive, researcher};
struct employee{
    int number;
    float salary;
    date first_day;
    etype position;
};

employee employee1, employee2, employee3;
char char1, position_of_employee1, position_of_employee2, position_of_employee3;

cout << "Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и \nдату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: ";
cin >> employee1.number >> position_of_employee1 >> employee1.salary 
    >> employee1.first_day.day >> char1 >> employee1.first_day.month >> char1 >> employee1.first_day.year;
cout << "Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и \nдату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: ";
cin >> employee2.number >> position_of_employee2 >> employee2.salary 
    >> employee2.first_day.day >> char1 >> employee2.first_day.month >> char1 >> employee2.first_day.year;
cout << "Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и \nдату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: ";
cin >> employee3.number >> position_of_employee3 >> employee3.salary 
    >> employee3.first_day.day >> employee3.first_day.month >> char1 >> employee3.first_day.year;

cout << "\nСотрудник № " << employee1.number << " поступил на работу " 
     << employee1.first_day.day << "/" << employee1.first_day.month << "/" << employee1.first_day.year 
     << " на должность ";

cout << "Сотрудник № " << employee2.number << " поступил на работу " 
    << employee2.first_day.day << "/" << employee2.first_day.month << "/" << employee2.first_day.year 
    << " на должность ";

cout << "Сотрудник № " << employee3.number << " поступил на работу " 
    << employee3.first_day.day << "/" << employee3.first_day.month << "/" << employee3.first_day.year 
    << " на должность ";

}

system("pause");
return 0 ;
}
```

Проблема в следующем: при выводе даты, которая записывается в **employeeN.first_day.day/month/year** первая и вторая даты, то бишь employee1 и employee2, выводятся нормально, хотя при отладке видно, что они никаких значений не принимают (там вопросы стоят). А третья дата вообще принимает странные значения: день нормально выдается, а год и месяц по -858993460. К сожалению, изображение прикрепить не могу (репутации мало). Очень хотелось бы понять,  что за магия

Comment: 1. Кто же пишет объявления типов внутри функции без явной необходимости?
2. В коде явно затесалась ошибка. По крайней мере есть лишняя закрывающаяся скобка.
3. Я так понимаю это код под win$?

Comment: 1.  Честно говоря, не понимаю, какие типы объявлены без небходимости? Я новичок, поэтому возможны ошибки подобного рода)) Вы же про функцию main? 
2. Действительно, скобка осталась так как удалял не относящуюся к вопросу часть кода.  Забыл ее удалить.  
3. Да, код под windows

Comment: @Shant, Вы бы пример входных данных привели.

Подозреваю, что даты Вы вводите так:

    20/10/2010

а `cin >> ...`, который Вы написали будет ее правильно вводить в таком виде:

    20 / 10 / 2010

Видите пробелы?

Comment: Попробовал сделать как вы говорите. Ввел с пробелами. Результат тот же. cin игнорирует пробелы, насколько я знаю. Вот значения переменных после первого cin-а. Дату он не считывает. Почему-то вопросы стоят. Все остальные значения принялись нормально

employee1 {number=1 salary=1500.0000 first_day=  {...} ...} main::__l2::employee

number 1 int
salary 1500.0000 float
first_day {day=??? month=??? year=??? } main::__l2::date
position -858993460 main::__l2::etype

Comment: Кстати, из-за определения типов внутри функции у дебаггера может сносить крышу и он будет неправильно показывать содержимое структур

Comment: Объясните, если не трудно, каким образом эти самые типы правильно объявлять? В книге Лафоре об этом ни слова)

Comment: @Михаил М, у нормальных g++/gdb в нормальном Linux крыша не едет...

    (gdb) p employee1
    $1 = {number = 0, salary = 0, first_day = {day = -8208, month =  32767, 
    year = 6299120}, position = laborer}
    (gdb)

--

@Shant, обычно принято определять типы вне функций. Чаще всего их надо определять вообще в заголовочных файлах. 

Это делается для  "согласования" кода при раздельной компиляции модулей (исходных файлов .c/.cpp).

Хотя для программы в 20 строк, состоящей только из `main()` это и не принципиально, но лучше сразу привыкать к правильному *стилю* программирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Shant](/users/13502/shant), (в комментарий не поместится) оттранслировал и запустил Вашу программу. (Выбросил только

```
system("pause");
return 0 ;
}
```

все равно этот текст за закрывающей main скобкой).

Вот результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и 
дату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: 1 2 3 21 / 10 / 2010
Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и 
дату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: 2 2 3 22 / 11 / 2011
Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и 
дату поступления на работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: 3 2 3 23 / 12 / 2012

Сотрудник № 1 поступил на работу 21/10/2010 на должность Сотрудник № 2 поступил на  работу 22/11/2011 на должность Сотрудник № 3 поступил на работу 23/0/-5229064 на   должность avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Видите, я ввел даты, как написал в комментарии и в принципе работает.

Теперь сравните 2 куска Вашего кода, ввод для сотрудника 2:

```
cin >> employee2.number >> position_of_employee2 >> employee2.salary 
    >> employee2.first_day.day >> char1 >> employee2.first_day.month >> char1 >>   employee2.first_day.year;
```

и ввод для сотрудника 3:

```
cout << "Введите номер, первую букву должности, оклад и \nдату поступления на      работу (дд/мм/гггг) сотрудника: ";
cin >> employee3.number >> position_of_employee3 >> employee3.salary 
    >> employee3.first_day.day >> employee3.first_day.month >> char1 >>    employee3.first_day.year;
```

в вводе данных 3-го сотрудника Вы пропустили ввод разделителя между

```
employee3.first_day.day И employee3.first_day.month
```

Будьте, по возможности, повнимательней.

Comment: Действительно, разделитель все поправил)) Спасибо) постараюсь в будущем быть более внимательным))